# using join() in Zend Model

Tags: php, zend-framework, join

I would like to create a model using join. This is the code i have:

```
$userModel = new self;
$select = $userModel->select();
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
   ->from(array('u' => 'accounts'),array('username','email'))
   ->where('u.id = ?',$id)
   ->join(array('i' => 'permissions'),'i.user_id = u.id',array('permission_type'));
$user = $userModel->fetchRow($select);
```

This works perfectly. The only problem is that the permission_type in permissions table has multiple entries. Using this code, I only get the first entry in the model! Is there a way to get around that, and get all the entries?

Answer (score 5):

I believe you might be looking for fetchAll. Like this:

```
...
$users = $userModel->fetchAll($select);
```

More information here http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.rowset.html

Comment: yes, and then use a foreach(or a loop of your choice) to get desired fields out of the rows.